# Using intermediate appPage xpages mobile

Tags: mobile, navigation, xpages

I have a simple issue, but I don´t how to solve the problem.
Using XPages Mobile controls, I have a document with some actions, and one of them is "Send to Signature".
The workflow is: select the signer of document (from names) and send to signature.
I need to show for the current user, one field to select the signer (I already have a field with typeahead funcion to select him).
I would like to use an intermediate appPage for this, but when I´m in the new appPage, the currentDocument is gone. 
How can I use the same document (opening from a dataView) for solve this problem?
Can I navigate between appPages (inside SinglePageApp) using the currentDocument??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at Mobile Value Picker on OpenNTF. The mobile prefix may need setting in XSP Properties to "Mobile_" (or it could be that I messed around with the development version after the last upload). But it gives code to have a button / link to go to a subsequent appPage to select values from a list. It starts from a DataView, to a document, to the selection page.

The project has not changed for a couple of years, but I've just tested it in Chrome setting user agent to Android and it still seems to work fine on 9.0.1 FP2.

Comment: I think this CC it's almost that I need, but not totally. I really need an intermediate page, because the action requires this behavior. When the user click the button, I move to another page to select/insert some additional information to start the workflow. Is this possible, keeping the currentDocument data?

Comment: Probably easiest is to use a separate dominoDocument datasource on the intermediate page. Set a viewScope variable for the UNID of the document being edited (it may require a save). Ensure ignoreRequestParams="true" (or you're editing a document defined by the URL). Also ensure resetContent="true".

Comment: currentDocument will only work if the dominoDocument is defined at the XPage level. But then you have the problem of how to refresh the details of that when you switch appPages - I'm not sure it's possible. One appPage will not be able to see a dominoDocument datasource defined in a different appPage - the rule here applies http://www.intec.co.uk/variable-scopes-and-passing-datasources-to-custom-controls/

Comment: I'm starting to think that I need have many divs inside the appPage and show/hide when I need. I'll try another possibilities and post the results here.